# Microsoft Access 2007 Input Form

Tags: ms-access

i am new in MS Access database and i have a problem to in insert form. I have already 
created a relational database in MS Access 2007. Now i need to create forms to create a insert data.

Let me go with details,
I have two tables, 
***User*** - Columns(*Id*[PK],*Name*,*Address*, *CountryID*[foreign key ]) 
and 
***Country*** - Columns(*CountryID*[PK],*Country Name*)

So i need to create a input form for ***User*** table that will display the *Country Names* as Dropdown/select box and the data will be showed from ***Country*** table. When anyone selects a country i will save the *CountryID* of that country.

I have checked in googled but almost all of them stores the same value that is selected but i don't want that. In my case if a *Country Name* is selected then corresponding *CountryID* will be saved.

Thanks in advance.

pks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right-click on your dropdown box.  Select the Properties menu.
- Scroll down to Row Source Type.  On the right side you should see a
  drop-down arrow.  Click it and select "Table/Query"
- Just above that you should see Row Source.  All the way to the right
  you should see an elipsis ("...").  Click that and select your Country
  table.
- Just below that you should see "Bound Column".  Make sure that's set
  to "1".  That will bind the first column to the "Value" property.

Now, when you select a country from the dropdown, it will display the name but will have a **value** of the ID.  So, Country.Text will be the name, Country.Value will be the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Go to design view of the form. you use the Control Wizard when you add a combobox to your form, a wizard will guide you through the steps of *storing* the ID, but *showing* the Name. Go to the Design tab. Click on the Combobox icon and then click on your form. If a wizard does not start, go back and turn on Use Control Wizards on the dropdown list under the icons. On the first screen, choose **I want the combo box to get the values from another table or query**. Then you'll specify Table: Country. Add CountryID and CountryName. Sort by CountryName. The next screen will hide the CountryID (because it is a primary key) and just show the CountryName. Specify that you want the value to be stored in the User table's CountryID field. Specify a label and click finish.

Comment: Hi Johnny Bones & Pteranodon,   Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It worked.